# Referencing field in SomeInterface when type is string | SomeInterface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a an interface which looks like the following

```
export interface IQuestion {
    id: string;
    _id: string;
    module: string | IModule;
}
```

I want to reference codes which is a property of module using dot notation as follows `module.codes`. The problem is Visual Studio Code is telling me codes does not exist on `string | IModule` or on `string`. How can I successfully make the required reference?

Here is the actual error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"codes"' can't be used to index type 'string | IModule'.
>     Property 'codes' does not exist on type 'string | IModule'.  TS7053

Comment: does the property "code" exist on IModule?

Comment: yes it does exist

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected behaviour when your are doing `module.code` but `module` is actually as `string`?

If it should return `undefined`, with recent version of Typescript you can do

```
// if module is a string, will return `undefined`
module?.code
```

[Typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) could also help you:

```
function isModule(mod: IModule | string): mod is IModule {
    return (mod as IModule).codes !== undefined;
}

// then later in your code
if isModule(question.module) question.module.code ...
```

Comment: Well i am using JSX in react. there is a section of your suggested answer that worked. (mod as IModule).codes did the solution